# Unable to open the 'uiautomatorviewer.bat', error message is displayed any ideas to fix it?

Tags: android, automation, appium, android-uiautomator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtMCV.jpg)

Error message is displayed:

Answer (score 0):

the error shows that it cannot find jvm, check your environmental variable for jdk and jre